# Terminal not working after installing ng-common

Tags: angular, terminal

I have installed `ng-common` and after that my terminal turns to blank and it's not working. I can't run any commands in that. What is the solution for this?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to /home
2. Show hidden files
3. Open .bashrc
4. Remove last line
   Angular ...
   source <>
5. Save & Now terminal can be accessed